# Fire form post when double clicking a list box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an html list box and want to double click an item in the list box which then does a form post to show me a new page.

Is this possible? In other words can I fire a form post from a double click?

I am using `Asp.net MVC 2` so need an action fired which will return the corresponding view for the selected item in the list box.

JD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#formName option').dblclick(function() {
  $('#formName').submit();
});
```

option would be html tag name for listbox element